# How do I check for duplicate column values in the table before I insert them with Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl

I am reading a file which contains a record in each line. I am extracting the contents of the file and inserting it as column values into a table. The problem I face is, suppose if i insert a record into a table after reading from the file, I want to remove the duplicate fields. For example:

```
NAME age time
Tom   21  10:30
Tom   21  12:21
```

After insertion into the table I want it to be:

```
NAME AGE TIME
tom   21  10:30
          12:21
```

It should eliminate the duplicates. If I add a unique condition while creating the table I face a problem that the distinct time field is not being inserted and results in an error in MySQL.

So how can I do this? I want some suggestions.

```
for my $test11 (sort keys %seen) {
    my $test1 = $seen{$test11}{'name'};
    my $test2 = $seen{$test11}{'pid'};
    my $test3 = $seen{$test11}{'type'};
    my $test4 = $seen{$test11}{'time1'};
    print "$test11\t$test1$test2$test3$test4\n";
}

#sub query_execute()
{
    $db_handle = &getdb_handle;
    $sth       = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tahle_new values('$sno','$id','$test1','$test4','$test2','$test3')");
```

`$test1` and `$test2` contain duplicates but not `$test3`.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to write to the database in each case you describe.

Comment: Also see previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334644/how-do-i-to-keep-the-values-of-a-column-unique-in-mysql

Comment: for my $test11(sort keys %seen){
my $test1 = $seen{$test11}{'name'};
my $test2 = $seen{$test11}{'pid'};
my $test3 = $seen{$test11}{'type'};
my $test4 = $seen{$test11}{'time1'};
print "$test11\t$test1$test2$test3$test4\n";
}
#sub query_execute()
{
$db_handle=&getdb_handle;
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tahle_new values('$sno','$id','$test1','$test4','$test2','$test3')" );

Comment: in the above $test1 and $test2 contains duplicates but not $test3

Answer (score 4):

Another way, is to define a unique key on 2 columns. Your key will be (Name, Age) and unique.
So on insert you'll get an error, or add to your request : '... ON DUPLICATE KEY...' and do something (or do nothing ;) )

And as **ysth** said, I would advise you not to insert your line with null values as the second one (null,null, 12:21)

Answer (score 2):

Each row has to have some value for each column.  Do you want what would otherwise be duplicates to be NULL?  It's hard to imagine a practical use for such a table.

One way is to have another table for each column you want to have non-duplicated with that column as a unique key; before adding the row to your main table, try to add the column values to the per column tables; if there is a duplicate error, clear that value before trying to add to the main table.

Comment: Note that this is not the most efficient way to detect dups, but is simple to do and should protect against race conditions if done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

ysth is correct, you should not have null values.  The duplication indicates that you need two tables.  One for the log and one to store information about the user.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id     INTEGER   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   TEXT      NOT NULL,
    age    INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE log (
    user   INTEGER REFERENCES user,
    time   TIME
);
```

The log table stores the integer id of the user and the time (and whatever else).  You'd insert an entry with:

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO log VALUES (?,?)", undef, $uid, $time);
```

You will have to remember or fetch the id of a user before noting an entry in the log.  I would recommend against using the name as the key as it is prone to change.  You can use `$dbh->last_insert_id` to get that after inserting a user.  Note the use of bind parameters to avoid SQL escaping and security problems.

Comment: I didn't say s/he shouldn't have null values; I said it was hard to imagine a case where that's what would be wanted.  I was actually hoping to elicit something saying the real problem is later on when the data is read from the database and output... :)

Comment: @sreeja: To expand on this a bit more: a database stores data for retrieval with queries. So you might e.g. want to pose a query listing all the `time`s for which the `name` is `Tom`. By `NULL`ifying duplicate data, you lose that ability (or it becomes very hard). Instead, you deduplicate using [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), i.e. factoring our the common values into a separate table. Now your queries become joins: they combine rows from the two tables. That is how relational databases were intended to be used.